# Android Studio AVD crashing (segmentation fault)

Tags: android, android-studio, vmware, android-virtual-device

I installed Android Studio on VMware with nested virtualization for the purpose of android penetration testing but whenever I launch my avd: Pixel 5 API 31 (Android 12) or any other, first of all it gives an error- [image: it seems to be an gpu driver issue]

I found a workaround for this i.e `emulator -avd Pixel_5 -gpu host` but whenever I click on more(3 dots) button the emulator crashes with the terminal output- [image]

Here's the video of the problem - [Problem Showcase](https://cdn.gilcdn.com/ContentMediaGenericFiles/215245b4eeadd68bf58a9a9b4f520668-Full.mp4?w=2560&h=1600&ia=1)